# Fix Function in Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

As I do not have much knowledge of javascript I need a little help from you.

This my script is a simple calculator but I can not make some functions work. I just need to

- When choosing a Radio Field it shows the value of the field
- And then immediately do the multiplication of dropdwon number box x value of the chosen radio field and add to the final calculation

Below script works, if possible I need a solution that wraps as little as possible in the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".valores1").change(function() {
    var total = 50;
    total += $('input[class="valores1"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
      return tot + Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
        
    var f = document.getElementById("valores7");    
    var itemSelecionadof = f.value;
         
    var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var primeiroDigito = (itemSelecionado.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito*100);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var d = document.getElementById("valores3");
    var itemSelecionado3 = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
    var primeiroDigito3 = (itemSelecionado3.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito3*itemSelecionadof);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var g = document.getElementById("valores4");
    var itemSelecionado4 = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;
    
    if (g.value == 1) {
     d.value = 0;
     g.value = 0;
     f.value = 0
     total = total-(primeiroDigito3*100);
     $('#total1').val(total);
     }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    
    //aqui pega primeiro digito
    
    $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));     
  });  
});
```

```html
PERA:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1"  name="direcao" value="10" id="option_1"  />
Banana:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="bilingue" value="15" id="option_1"  /><br />

<select id="valores2"   class="valores1 form-control" name="tipo carnes" >
    <option value="0">Meat</option>
    <option value="1">1 Picanha</option>
    <option value="2">2 Picanhas</option>
    <option value="3">3 Picanhas</option>
     
</select>  <br /><br />

Small Box<input type="radio" class="valores1" name="normal" value="100" id="valores7" />
Big Box<input type="radio" class="valores1" name="normal"    value="150" id="valores7"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;====>View Value of the box<input type="text" size="5"  readonly="" id="valorsacola" name="valor da sacola"  value="0.00" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: green; "    />            
<br />
<select id="valores3"   class="valores1 form-control" name="nsacolas" >
    <option value="0">Number of box</option>
    <option value="1">x1</option>
    <option value="2">x2</option>
    <option value="3">x3</option>
    
</select>  
<br /><hr />

delete box calculation
<select id="valores4"   class="valores1 form-control" name="cadeirinha2" >
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">zerar</option>
    <option value="2">x2</option>    
</select>  
<br /><br /><br />

minimum consummation
<input type="text" size="5"  readonly="" name="valor" id="total1" value="50.00" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: green; "    />            
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fistly the radiobuttons have the ID repeated this is not valid, an ID must be unique. The `name` attribute is the suitable for this, following this idea the code will be something like this:

```
Small Box <input type="radio" class="valores1" name="normal" value="100" name="valores7" />
Big Box<input type="radio" class="valores1" name="normal" value="150" name="valores7"/>
```

As you added a listener to look when `valores1` change, this way you can do the change of this radiobuttons.

```
$("input[name=valores7]").change(function(e) {
    //this change the value in your input
    $('#valorsacola').val($(this).val());

    //is not clear for me how you calculate the total but with the value of
    // $(this).val() you can retrieve it.  
});
```